# How to get constant number of requests per scenario

Tags: java, load-testing, gatling

I have multiple scenarios executed in 'setUp()' method. What I want to achieve is to get 4000 requests per minute for each scenario then repeat all. I want to run the test at night for several hours.

How can I do this?

This is my actual code:

```
{
    List<PopulationBuilder> scenarioList = new ArrayList<>();
    scenarioList.add(get.injectOpen(constantUsersPerSec(4000).during(Duration.ofSeconds(10))));
    scenarioList.add(search.injectOpen(constantUsersPerSec(4000).during(Duration.ofSeconds(10))));
    scenarioList.add(download.injectOpen(constantUsersPerSec(4000).during(Duration.ofSeconds(10))));
    /* Shuffle list */
    Collections.shuffle(scenarioList);

    setUp(create.injectOpen(nothingFor(5), constantUsersPerSec(4000).during(Duration.ofSeconds(10)))
            .andThen(scenarioList)
            .andThen(delete.injectOpen(constantUsersPerSec(4000).during(Duration.ofSeconds(10)))))
            .throttle(
                    reachRps(4000).in(10),
                    holdFor(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
            )
            .protocols(httpProtocol);
}
```